# Reverse proxy server in DMZ with separate server for nginx (docker)

Tags: webserver, docker, dmz

Does it makes sense to create two separate docker hosts (VMs) for reverse-proxy and web application?

My first idea was to put the web-exposed application in my separated VLAN (DMZ) where only ports 80 and 443 are exposed to the internet then use firewall to only allow one-way traffic from LAN to these ports but in future I'd also probably want to have the ability to add other containers which are only for local use, so it seems a bit weird to me for that server to reside in DMZ.

So my question is whether it would be more secure to put that VM into a LAN VLAN and create a second VM for only reverse proxy, which would reside in DMZ with proper firewall rules and disabled SSH.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why do you want to use DMZ? Seperating resources makes sense, because if someone let's say hacks in the frontend which would be the Reverse Proxy they can't get to the web app and its' stored secrets that easily..

Comment: Thanks. From what I've read it would be best practice to put web exposed apps in a DMZ, is that not correct?

Comment: It depends on your network setup, but imho - not really.